# contraction of indexes takes long time

Tags: summation, index, feyncalc

I have got an expression which has more than a hundred terms being added up together, each of terms are similar in mathematical form.`bingo[i_, j_] := Contract[cqpart[i, j] gammapart[i, j]]`with `cqpart[i_, j_] := Contract[cp[i] cpc[j]]` and `gammapart[a_, b_] := Contract[TR[gp[a].gpc[b]]]`
for example

```
bingo[7,1]=Contract[Contract[TR[gp[7].gpc[1]]]Contract[cq[7]cqc[1]]]
```

while

```
gp[7]=(GSD[p3]+m).GAD[γ].(GSD[p4+k]+m).Contract[(FVD[2p4+k,μ]GAD[ν]+
      FVD[2p4+k,ν].GAD[μ]).gps[μ,ν,ρ,σ]].(GSD[p4]-m);
gpc[1]=GAD[ϵ];
cp[7]=xyz[k1,k2,-k1-k2,α,β,γ];
cpc[1]=Z[-k1,-k2,k1+k2-k,ρ,σ,α,β,ϵ];
```

while

```
gps[μ_,ν_,ρ_,σ_]:=(MTD[μ,ρ]-(FVD[k,μ]FVD[k,ρ])/SPD[k,k])(MTD[ν,σ]-                    
(FVD[k,ν]FVD[k,σ])/SPD[k,k])+(MTD[μ,σ]-(FVD[k,μ]FVD[k,σ])
/SPD[k,k])(MTD[ν,ρ]-(FVD[k,ν]FVD[k,ρ])/SPD[k,k])-2/3  
(MTD[μ,ν]-(FVD[k,μ]FVD[k,ν])/SPD[k,k])(MTD[ρ,σ]-(FVD[k,ρ]FVD[k,σ]) 
/SPD[k,k])

xyz[k1_, k2_, k3_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
MTD[α, β] FVD[(k1 - k2), γ] + 
MTD[β, γ] FVD[(k2 - k3), α] + 
MTD[γ, α] FVD[(k3 - k1), β]

Z[k1_,k2_,k3_,μ_,ν_,α_,β_,γ_]:=
Y[k1,μ,ν,α,β,γ]+Y[k2,μ,ν,β,γ,α]+Y[k3,ν,μ,γ,α,β]+
Y[k1,ν,μ,α,β,γ]+Y[k2,ν,μ,β,γ,α]+Y[k3,ν,μ,γ,α,β]
```

and `Y` is defined as below

```
 Y[k_,μ_,ν_,α_,β_,γ_]:=FVD[k,μ](MTD[ν,β]MTD[α,γ]-MTD[ν,γ]MTD[α,β])+
 FVD[k,β](MTD[μ,α]MTD[ν,γ]-1/2 MTD[μ,ν]MTD[α,γ])-
 FVD[k,γ](MTD[μ,α]MTD[ν,β]-1/2 MTD[μ,ν]MTD[α,β])
```

The computation is not complicated, but tedious. `bingo[7,1]` takes nearly 156 seconds, so the total amount of time is really long. I am wondering is there a better way which take shorter time to contract so many Lorentz indexes?

> [Contract references](http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Contract/index.html)

Comment: You have several mistakes. Arguments of functions in Mathematica are typed with `[ ]`, so your function `Y` (and others) should be typed as `Y[ ...]`. Further, what is `Contract[ ]`? Can you cook your problem down to a minimal example with all definitions so we can test it?

Comment: @ Mauricio Lobos Thanks

Comment: May I suggest directly contacting the developer and FeynCalc community by posting your question [on the FeynCalc forum](https://feyncalc.github.io/forum)?  You'll very likely get a response from them.

Comment: Could you please fix the syntax of your example? There is a missing closing brace in `gps` and it should be `cp` and `cpc` instead of `cq` and `cqc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General recommendations are

1. Do not put intermediate instances of `Contract`, the function works best on the full expression
2. Do not put momenta inside lists like `-{k1+k2}`, this is a totally unsupported syntax

Apart from that, `Contract` is much faster in the current [development version](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#dev_automatic_installation) (which will become FeynCalc 9.3)

On my laptop (i5-6440HQ with 32 GB RAM running Fedora 25 with Mathematica 11.0.1) the following

```
Y[k_, mu_, nu_, al_, be_, ga_] := 
  FVD[k, mu] (MTD[nu, be] MTD[al, ga] - MTD[nu, ga] MTD[al, be]) + 
   FVD[k, be] (MTD[mu, al] MTD[nu, ga] - 
      1/2 MTD[mu, nu] MTD[al, ga]) - 
   FVD[k, ga] (MTD[mu, al] MTD[nu, be] - 
      1/2 MTD[mu, nu] MTD[al, be]);

Z[k1_, k2_, k3_, mu_, nu_, al_, be_, ga_] := 
  Y[k1, mu, nu, al, be, ga] + Y[k2, mu, nu, be, ga, al] + 
   Y[k3, nu, mu, ga, al, be] + Y[k1, nu, mu, al, be, ga] + 
   Y[k2, nu, mu, be, ga, al] + Y[k3, nu, mu, ga, al, be];

gps[mu_, nu_, rho_, 
   si_] := (MTD[mu, rho] - (FVD[k, mu] FVD[k, rho])/SPD[k, k]) (MTD[
       nu, si] - (FVD[k, nu] FVD[k, si])/SPD[k, k]) + (MTD[mu, 
       si] - (FVD[k, mu] FVD[k, si])/SPD[k, k]) (MTD[nu, 
       rho] - (FVD[k, nu] FVD[k, rho])/SPD[k, k]) - 
   2/3 (MTD[mu, nu] - (FVD[k, mu] FVD[k, nu])/SPD[k, k]) (MTD[rho, 
       si] - (FVD[k, rho] FVD[k, si]/SPD[k, k]));

xyz[k1_, k2_, k3_, al_, be_, ga_] := 
 MTD[al, be] FVD[(k1 - k2), ga] + MTD[be, ga] FVD[(k2 - k3), al] + MTD[ga, al] FVD[(k3 - k1), be]

gp = (GSD[p3] + m).GAD[
    ga].(GSD[p4 + k] + m).(FVD[2 p4 + k, mu] GAD[nu] + 
     FVD[2 p4 + k, nu].GAD[mu]).gps[mu, nu, rho, si].(GSD[p4] - m);
cp = xyz[k1, k2, -k1 + k2, al, be, ga];
cpc = Z[-k1, -k2, k1 + k2 - k, rho, si, al, be, eps];
AbsoluteTiming[res = Contract[TR[gp.GAD[eps]] cp cpc];] // First
```

requires around 31 seconds with FeynCalc 9.2 but only 3 seconds with FeynCalc 9.3
[image]

Edit: Why it is better not to use intermediate instances of `Contract`:

Consider

```
TS[a_, b_, x_] := SPD[x] MTD[a, b] - FVD[x, a] FVD[x, b];
exp = Product[TS[ aa[i], aa[i - 1], x[i]], {i, 1, 9}];
```

Now compare

```
res1 = Contract[exp] // AbsoluteTiming;
res1 // First
```

which requires 0.89 seconds with

```
res2 = Contract[
    Contract[exp[[1 ;; 3]]] Contract[exp[[4 ;; 6]]] Contract[
      exp[[6 ;; 9]]]] // AbsoluteTiming;
res2 // First
```

which takes 2.33 seconds, i.e. almost three times longer.

The reason is that `Contract` implements some algorithms (it was the original idea of Rolf Mertig) to speed up contractions of certain products of Lorentz tensors. However, when the products are all expanded (which is what you get in the output of intermediate `Contract`'s) these algorithms cannot be applied and you end up with the worst case performance.

Comment: It has been a great help, thank you, why don't put intermediate instances of `Contract`, I thought it takes more time to contract indexes in one go than the time doing it step by step.

Comment: I expanded my answer regarding intermediate instances of `Contract`.